# Flutter: how to log an Android system message that will get picked up by logcat?

Tags: android, flutter

If I want to log a message that Android Studio will show in its console, I can do this:

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

void main() {
  log('Hello world!');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

But if I package the app, run it and then look for it with `logcat`, it's not there.

```
flutter build apk
adb install build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.myapp/.MainActivity
adb logcat -t '12-08 00:00:00.000' | grep Hello
```

This results in empty output. So how do I log a system message, not just an IDE debug message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print()` or `debugPrint()`.

> You have two options for logging for your application. The first is to use stdout and stderr. Generally, this is done using print() statements, or by importing dart:io and invoking methods on stderr and stdout.

> If you output too much at once, then Android sometimes discards some log lines. To avoid this, use debugPrint(), from Flutter’s foundation library.

Check [Debugging Flutter apps programmatically](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/code-debugging) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to get the log messages inside your flutter application check the plugin called [logcat_monitor](https://pub.dev/packages/logcat_monitor) on pub.dev.

Its biggest advantage over the other logcat plugin is that it allows continuous monitoring of logcat messages.

Follows a screenshot example:

[image]

## how to use

Add the dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  logcat_monitor: ^0.0.4
```

1. Create a function to consume the *logcat* messages

```dart
  void _mylistenStream(dynamic value) {
    if (value is String) {
      _logBuffer.writeln(value);
    }
  }
```

2. Register your function as a listener to get logs then use it in anyway within your app.

```dart
    LogcatMonitor.addListen(_mylistenStream);
```

3. Start the logcat monitor passing the filter parameters as defined in *logcat* tool.

```dart
    await LogcatMonitor.startMonitor("*.*");
```